# MCMC( Markov Chain Monte-Carlo Simulation )

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $Q=[q(i,j)]$ is a transitional probability matrix for an irreducible Markov chain. Suppose also $\lbrace X_{n}, n \geq 0 \rbrace$ is Markov Chain such that if  $ X_{n}=i$, generate $Y=j$ such that $P{Y=j}=q(i,j)$, and if $Y=j$ set $X_{n+1}=j$ with probability $ \alpha (i, j)$, that is $P \lbrace X_{n+1}=j | X_{n}=i \rbrace= \alpha (i, j)$, and set $X_{n+1}=i$ with probability $1- \alpha (i, j)$,  that is   $P \lbrace X_{n+1}=i | X_{n}=i \rbrace=1- \alpha (i, j)$. Show that  $$P \lbrace Y_{n+1}=j | Y_{n}=i \rbrace= \alpha (i, j) q(i,j) \quad j \neq i$$ and that  $P \lbrace Y_{n+1}=i | Y_{n}=i \rbrace= q(i,i) + \displaystyle \sum _{k \neq i} (1-\alpha (k, j) )q(k,j)$.

Comment: I want a well detailed answer to this one please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}P \lbrace Y_{n+1}=j | Y_{n}=i \rbrace =P_{ij}=Q_{ji}..........(i) \end{equation} (because the algorithm given which is the Hastings-Metropolis Algorithm generates a time reversible markov chain.)

Now we are  told that $Q$ is defined on the Markov chain $ \lbrace X_{n}, n=1,2,3,.. \rbrace$ it follows that  equation $(i)$ can be written as \begin{equation}P_{ij}= P\lbrace  X_{n}=i | X_{n+1}=j\rbrace............(ii) \end{equation} (we have written this based on the definition of  Q in the book, Ross, S., (2007), page 268, introduction to prob. models)

Now we would like to partition the set $\lbrace  X_{n}=i | X_{n+1}=j\rbrace$ about $\lbrace  X_{n-1}\rbrace$ and hence we obtain $\lbrace  X_{n}=i | X_{n+1}=j\rbrace = \cup _{k=0} ^{\infty} \lbrace  X_{n}=i, X_{n-1}=k | X_{n+1}=j\rbrace$ hence equation $(ii)$ can be rewritten as \begin{equation}P_{ij}= P \lbrace \cup _{k=0} ^{\infty} \lbrace  X_{n}=i, X_{n-1}=k | X_{n+1}=j\rbrace \rbrace............(iii) \end{equation}

Now using the third axiom of the definition of probability, Ross, S., page 4, we have \begin{equation}P_{ij}=  \sum _{k=0} ^{\infty}P   \lbrace  X_{n}=i, X_{n-1}=k | X_{n+1}=j \rbrace............(iv) \end{equation}

From the definition of conditional probability we have \begin{equation}P_{ij}=  \sum _{k=0} ^{\infty}P   \lbrace  X_{n}=i| X_{n-1}=k , X_{n+1}=j \rbrace P\lbrace  X_{n-1}=k | X_{n+1}=j \rbrace............(v) \end{equation}

Now from the fact that $ \lbrace X_{n}, n=1,2,3,.. \rbrace$ is a Markov Chain we can rewrite equation $(v)$ as \begin{equation}P_{ij}=  \sum _{k=0} ^{\infty}P   \lbrace  X_{n}=i| X_{n-1}=k  \rbrace P\lbrace  X_{n-1}=k | X_{n+1}=j \rbrace............(vi) \end{equation}

Since these are one step probabilities equation $(vi)$ should be written as \begin{equation}P_{ij}=  \sum _{k=0} ^{\infty}P_{ik} Q_{jk}= \sum _{k=0} ^{\infty} Q_{jk}P_{ik}  ............(vii) \end{equation}

Using properties of summation we rewrite equation $(vii)$ as \begin{equation}P_{ij}=  \sum _{k \neq i} ^{\infty}P_{ik} Q_{jk}+ P_{ii} Q_{ji}............(viii) \end{equation}

Now if $i=j$ we have $Q_{ii}=1$ and $P_{ij}=P_{ii}$ so that the equation $(viii)$ can be written as \begin{equation}P_{ii}=  \sum _{k \neq i} ^{\infty}P_{ik} Q_{jk}+ P_{ii} ............(ix) \end{equation}

And we are told that when $j=i$ that is when $X_{n+1}=i$ then $P \lbrace X_{n+1}=i | X_{n}=i \rbrace= 1-\alpha(i,j)$, hence we write the equation $(ix)$ as  \begin{equation}P_{ii}=  \sum _{k \neq i} ^{\infty} (1-\alpha (k, j))q(j,k)+ P_{ii} ............(x) \end{equation}

However we note from $(vii)$ that the RHS is $(PQ)_{ij}=p(i,j)q(i,j)$ when $i \neq j$

Comment: It was an assignment problem from Ross and I got this answer through thinking rather than references